# How do I navigate from the JQuery panel items based upon an attribute in the json feed

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

New to Kendo and thought this would be dead easy, but am struggling to find an answer. I have a JQuery Panel Bar based upon a json object. I want the screen to navigate to a url defined within the json. Each item has it's own unique url in the json.

I thought about adding a template with a hidden span and adding a custom class and a data-itemid attribute, but am not sure if I am over thinking this. I don't know if Kendo has a simple way of doing this that I am missing.

Also, is there a Kendo method for navigating, or should I just use window.location in a function.

Finally, I noticed there is a select method I can use when defining the panel bar, However, lots of folks just seem to write a function using function onSelect(e)... within a script tag. Which method is the better method for sending the user to a new screen when a panel item is clicked?

My data would look something like this if defined inline:

```
data: [
                {
                    id: 1, text: "Furniture", items: [
                      { id: 2, text: "Tables & Chairs", url: "mydomain.com/link1" },
                      { id: 3, text: "Sofas"", url: "mydomain.com/link2" },
                      { id: 4, text: "Occasional Furniture"", url: "mydomain.com/link3" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 5, text: "Decor", items: [
                      { id: 6, text: "Bed Linen" ", url: "mydomain.com/link4"},
                      { id: 7, text: "Curtains & Blinds" ", url: "mydomain.com/link5"},
                      { id: 8, text: "Carpets" ", url: "mydomain.com/link6"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [dataUrlField](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/panelbar/configuration/dataurlfield) to specify which property of your JSON objects contains the navigation URL. In your case, the solution might look something like this (working demo here https://dojo.telerik.com/UvEHomuB):

```
<div id="panelbar"></div>
<script>
var items = [
            {
                id: 1, text: "Furniture", items: [
                  { id: 2, text: "Tables & Chairs", url: "mydomain.com/link1" },
                  { id: 3, text: "Sofas", url: "mydomain.com/link2" },
                  { id: 4, text: "Occasional Furniture", url: "mydomain.com/link3" }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 5, text: "Decor", items: [
                  { id: 6, text: "Bed Linen", url: "mydomain.com/link4"},
                  { id: 7, text: "Curtains & Blinds", url: "mydomain.com/link5"},
                  { id: 8, text: "Carpets", url: "mydomain.com/link6"}
                ]
            }
        ];
$("#panelbar").kendoPanelBar({
  dataUrlField: "url",
  dataSource: items
});
</script>
```

This probably represents the easiest solution to your problem, unless you need to do something more specific when a user selects a node. On the subject of navigation generally, I'd recommend you take a look at the kendo [SPA framework](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/spa/overview). It helps you to build a site which only reloads parts of the page when the user navigates around the site, rather than forcing the browser to reload the entire page. Hope this helps.